# Jekyll Template/Liquid Code for Auto Generated Side Menu

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have a side menu auto generated from the headings of a tutorial. I can either add them to a list in the front matter or have it auto detect them, but I need to write some code that only generates a side menu of appropriate length. Something like [this](http://learn.adafruit.com/beaglebone-black-installing-operating-systems/choosing-an-operating-system)(you can see the side menu in large windows) but I would use the side nav or preferabbly accordion modules present in Foundation 4. I guess it would have to first count the words or phrases i nthe list, then generate a side module in a loop for the required number of times.

Since I'm not too familiar with jekyll and Liquid templating code, I though I would ask here first and find out if anyone can give me a hand. If it's difficult a nudge toward where to start would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be much better off just hard-coding the side menu and using a layout to include it on each page.

At the start of each file that makes up the tutorial, include a YAML front matter section like this:

```
---
layout: sidebar
---
```

Then in your `_layouts` folder include a layout with the name `sidebar.html`, which describes the sidebar like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
        <!--Sidebar content goes here-->
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        {{ content }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```